# Installed Applications are missing after restart : Ubuntu 12.04 

Tags: 12.04, package-management

i am new to ubuntu and downloaded the latest 12.04,however I installed programs such as chrome, adobe etc after restarting I can't find none of those and home screen of ubuntu looks like untouched please help.so do i have to download them again ? .Thanks!

Comment: open your terminal and type as this dpkg -s <your_app_name > and look at the status field .

Comment: well it shows following msg ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -s chrome
Package `chrome' is not installed and no info is available.
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents. Is there any way shoul I save these  before shutting down.? Thnkx

Comment: ok previously how you installed them ?

Comment: I installed chrome from internet and it was running fine in the last session of ubuntu

Comment: Are you by any chance running directly from the liveCD, and did not install Ubuntu to your disk? It sounds exactly like that. When running from CD/DVD, all changes you do (including additional software installed) are lost as soon as you shut down.

Answer (score 1):

try to press the "windows key" and search for chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Open the dash (super key or click top of launcher), and start typing the name of one of the programs.  It should search and find it for you.

Comment: Thanks but it works fine on current session as soon as i restart my system ..everything seems to be disappeared as if they were never downloaded and I can't find them in the dash even...

Comment: Odd.  Does Ubuntu Software Center still show them as installed?

Comment: Another thought, you aren't running off the live cd are you?

Comment: No, Software Center does'nt show them either...Also I m running ubuntu 12.04 from a USB stick..

Comment: If the USB isn't made with persistence mode it won't store your installed files. Whatever you are experiencing that is expected.

Comment: orite..i was'nt very sure nywayz is there any way to check my usb is in persistent mode?

Comment: I saw it as an option when creating a bootable USB with unetbootin IIRC.  Good utility to use for making bootable USB drives.